# cannot export partition by date table from BigQuery to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, extract, partitioning, bq

I'm trying to export the partition by day table to the GCP bucket.
My main goal is to create daily files in the GCP.

Here is my simple first test for the extraction:

```
bq extract --destination_format=CSV test.test_table$20210719 gs://test_partition/part_col=20210716/test_*.csv
```

`test_table` is a partition table and I do have 7k rows for the date 2021-07-19.
However, when I run this line, I get this

```
BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job 'test-net:bqjob_1234456789: Not found: Table test-
net:temp.test_partitiontime0210719 was not found in location EU
```

As you can see above the table name is `temp.test_partitiontime0210719` there is no `2` at the beginning of it. Whenever $ sign is included in the table name, the first character after it is being removed.

I've tried to apply this GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#exporting_table_data).
Also, I have tried this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523109/7931992), but it hasn't worked for me.

How can I extract the partition table to the GCP for a specific date?

Comment: It should be unix issue. Try to add simple quote around your dataset.table name

Comment: that's great it worked. thank you. if you type your answer below, I can mark this question as solved with your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a linux side effect. If you put `$something` linux search for an environment variable with the key `something`.

To skip that, you can use simple quote `'` to say to linux: "Hey, do not evaluate this environment variable token", so do this

```
bq extract --destination_format=CSV 'test.test_table$20210719' gs://test_partition/part_col=20210716/test_*.csv
```